# PlayerController: Possess vs AcknowledgePossession vs SetPawn

Tags: unreal-engine4

What is the difference between and the calling sequence (related to each other) of

- `APlayerController::Possess()`
- `APlayerController::AcknowledgePossession()`
- `APlayerController::SetPawn()`

What function should I prefer to use (override), to trigger something once the player controller possessed a pawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetPawn()` will be called internally, when you call `Possess()`. In 4.22, `Possess()` is marked virtual final, you should override OnPossess() to do your specific job, but you can still call `OnPossess()` to change your controlled pawn, then `OnPossess()` will be automatically called.

`Possess()` only runs on server, the same as `OnPossess()`. So in clients, you should override `AcknowledgePossession()` to do a similar job in `OnPossess()`, it will be called when server change controlled pawn.